# Apache mod_proxy_uwsgi and unix domain sockets

Tags: apache, config, uwsgi, unix-socket

I have a uwsgi server running for unix domain socket

```
[uwsgi]
...
socket = /var/run/someuwsgi.sock
socket = localhost:9987
...
```

The mod_proxy_uwsgi is installed

In apache config has that line:
    ProxyPass /some uwsgi://localhost:9987

And it is working.

Question: what should be  the apache config line to go through unix domain socket
   /var/run/someuwsgi.sock 
?
I tried

```
ProxyPass /some uwsgi:///var/run/someuwsgi.sock
```

and got

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Also tried

```
ProxyPass /some uwsgi://unix:///var/run/someuwsgi.sock
```

and got

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /some/.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: unix:
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

[Starting from Apache 2.4.7](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass), support for Unix sockets has been added. The syntax is pretty simple:

```
ProxyPass / unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock|uwsgi://
```

Comment: It seems that it is available since 2.4.7 exactly. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Comment: I had to put `localhost/` on the end.   Maybe because I was going to a sub directory

    ProxyPass /e_app/ unix:/var/run/uwsgi/app/app1/socket|uwsgi://localhost/

Comment: #metoo . . . Format needed to be:
    ProxyPass / unix:/a/b/c/d/uwsgi.sock|uwsgi://localhost/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the apache proxy api does not (currently) support unix sockets

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on the other answer and my experience this seems to be the correct syntax:

```
ProxyPass /some unix:/var/run/someuwsgi.sock|uwsgi://localhost
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

> In 2.4.7 and later, support for using a Unix Domain Socket is available by using a target which prepends unix:/path/lis.sock|. For example, to proxy HTTP and target the UDS at /home/www.socket, you would use unix:/home/www.socket|http://localhost/whatever/. Since the socket is local, the hostname used (in this case localhost) is moot, but it is passed as the Host: header value of the request.